# Assembler of Raspberry pi OS running on VirtualBox unable to find second operand

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have written program in VM editor of Raspberry pi Operating System. When I want to execute the file I get the error

```
Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
Error: no such instruction : 'swi 0'
```

MY Assembly program on Vim is

**.text  

.global _start 

_start: 

MOV R0, #65 

MOV R1, #1 

SWI 0**

Instruction that I am using to execute the file is

```
as -o asmtut.o asmtut.s
```

I have also tried

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o asmtut.o asmtut.s
```

but then I get the error
bash: arm-none-eabi-as: command not found.

Comment: What is the target as printed on the last line of `as --version`?

Comment: I am a complete beginner kindly explain your answer.

Comment: Run `as --version`. What does it print on the last line. E.g. _"This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-linux-eabi'"_

Comment: This assembler was configured for a target of 'i686-linux-gnu'

Comment: @hamza You have an x86 assembler while you need an ARM assembler.  Install the required toolchain packages.

Comment: how to find the required toolchain packages?

Answer (score 1):

That is an ARM assembly language program.

You have a computer with an x86 processor, rather than one with a ARM processor such as a Raspberry Pi.

If you want to program that computer in it's native assembly language you need to do so in x86 assembly language.

If you want to learn ARM assembly language you need a CPU emulator. Assuming Raspberry Pi OS is sufficiently like Ubuntu you can install the packages:

- `binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf` (assembler and linker)
- `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` (if you want a C compiler)
- `qemu-user` (to run ARM Linux programs on Linux)

Also that program is not a correct Linux program, nor any other OS I know of.